# Error al pasar token a través de api por fetch

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch

tengo una api que recoge un id y un token para eliminar un elemento con el id que especifico de mongodb, todo va bien cuando hago el delete por postman pero cuando llamo el api a través de una función me retorna un mensaje como si no se estuviera especificando el token, cuando meto el token manualmente (el que genero a través de localStorage) me deja eliminar el elemento de la base de datos pero no se me elimina cuando llamo la función...

```
  export function deleteBrieffApi(token, id){//El id lo tomo a través del elemento _id (brieffs._id)
  const url = `${basePath}/${apiVersion}/delete-brieff/${id}`;
  const params = {
    method: "DELETE",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: token,
    },
  };

  return fetch(url, params)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
}
```

cuando hago console.log de la funcion que me retorna el token desde el auth me lanza el token correcto que tengo en el localStorage pero cuando lo vinculo directamente al api `deleteBrieffApi(token, id)` la consola me retorna un error como si no se estuviera especificando el header (el Authorization específicamente)

esta es la función que retorna el token y el id y lo envia al api

```
const deleteBrieff = (brieffs) => {
    const accessToken = getAccessTokenApi();
    console.log(accessToken);
    confirm({
      title: "Eliminando portafolio...",
      content: `¿Estás seguro de eliminar el portafolio "${
        brieffs.title ? brieffs.title : brieffs.id
      }".`,
      okText: "Eliminar",
      okType: "danger",
      cancelText: "Cancelar",
      onOk() {
        deleteBrieffApi(accessToken, brieffs._id)
          .then((response) => {
            const typeNotification =
              response.code === 200 ? "success" : "warning";
            notification[typeNotification]({
              message: response.message,
            });
            setReloadBrieff(true);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            notification["error"]({
              message: "Error del servidor.",
            });
          });
      },
    });
  };
```

aclaro que cuando pongo el token completo en el header (Authorization: "54646asd...token") tampoco me lo válida como un token y me lanza el error...

no sé si me falte especificar algo en el header del api pero realmente no entiendo muy bien porque me está sucediendo esto... gracias.

Comment: que estas usando para validar ese token en tu api?

Comment: En el api que elimina los datos de la db nada, pero tengo un auth que se encarga de obtener el token y el refreshToken, sé que el token en sí no es porque hasta el momento no me ha fallado y no me falla con nada más, tengo varios cruds con auth en middleware y no me falla nada mas, solo esto

Comment: pero si no tienes que valide el token por que lo envías?

Comment: Sí lo tengo validado pero en un api externo que se encarga exclusivamente de los token

Comment: No se si será esto pero en  los params, estas especificando los headers con `header:` , y debería ser `headers:`